# Mac Mini refuses my password even if its the correct one

Tags: password, mac-mini, administrator

As I wanted to keep my data more secure, I decided to change my admin password (my only account). I wrote my password on a piece of paper too (new passwords are easily forgotten).

I try to connect back to my account, but the password is just refused, an incorrect password every time, I think of a typo and try different combinations close to the original before resigning to just reset the password in Recovery Mode.

In Recovery Mode, I successfully reset the password (there is also a 'postgres' user a database I have installed but never appeared on the login screen previously), this time I chose an easy password where I won't make typos, I reboot and try to login with no success.

I think this is because I am using a Windows keyboard and there must be some type of mismatch or is it something else and this is a known problem on a Mac Mini?

Comment: Which model of Mac Mini? The new M1, the 2018 T2, and previous Minis behave differently. Also: at worst, you can wipe the disk and restore your data from your backup?

Comment: The new M1, I found the solution now, it was a keyboard mismatch.

Comment: I use a french keyboard maybe it reverted back to US on the login screen when I changed passwords I am not sure what exactly happened. However I didn't lose any access to my keychains, so anyone who have access to my pc and know how to enter recovery mode can just login and see my passwords ?

Comment: @iam_pff Your keychain is encrypted based on your login password; in recovery mode, someone could copy the keychain files, but without your password they wouldn't be able to decrypt the contents.